# PlotLabel multiple plots inside a Table

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling

```
p = {1, 1}; q = {3, 2};
ray = Line[{p, q}];
t[v_, p_] := ReflectionTransform[v, p];
r[deg_, p_] := RotationTransform[deg, p];
s[x_] := TranslationTransform[x];

Table[Framed@
  Graphics[{ray, 
    f[ray], {PointSize[Medium], Point[p], Point[q], f[Point[p]], 
     f[Point[q]]},
    Text["P", Offset[{-5, 10}, p]],
    Text["Q", Offset[{0, 10}, q]] ,
    Text["P'", Offset[{-5, 10}, f[p]]],
    Text["Q'", Offset[{0, 10}, f[q]]]},
   Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, ImageSize -> {200, 200}],
 {f, {t[{0, 1}, {0, 0}], r[90 °, {0, 0}], s[{1, 2}]}}]
```

[image: output]

I got this output. I'm only missing the PlotLabels, how do I add them for each plot inside Table? I tried adding a second iterator list after f but then I get 9 plots instead of 3 as output.

```
p = {1, 1}; q = {3, 2};
ray = Line[{p, q}];
t[v_, p_] := ReflectionTransform[v, p];
r[deg_, p_] := RotationTransform[deg, p];
s[x_] := TranslationTransform[x];

Table[Framed@
  Graphics[{ray, 
    f[ray], {PointSize[Medium], Point[p], Point[q], f[Point[p]], 
     f[Point[q]]},
    Text["P", Offset[{-5, 10}, p]],
    Text["Q", Offset[{0, 10}, q]] ,
    Text["P'", Offset[{-5, 10}, f[p]]],
    Text["Q'", Offset[{0, 10}, f[q]]]},
   Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotLabel -> label, 
   ImageSize -> {200, 200}],
 {f, {t[{0, 1}, {0, 0}], r[90 °, {0, 0}], s[{1, 2}]}},
 {label, {"Reflection", "Rotation", "Translation"}}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

"13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)"

ClearAll["Global`*"]

p = {1, 1}; q = {3, 2};
ray = Line[{p, q}];
t[v_, p_] := ReflectionTransform[v, p];
r[deg_, p_] := RotationTransform[deg, p];
s[x_] := TranslationTransform[x];

Framed@Graphics[{ray, #[[1]][ray],
      {PointSize[Medium],
       Point[p], Point[q], #[[1]][Point[p]], #[[1]][Point[q]]},
      Text["P", Offset[{-5, 10}, p]],
      Text["Q", Offset[{0, 10}, q]],
      Text["P'", Offset[{-5, 10}, #[[1]][p]]],
      Text["Q'", Offset[{0, 10}, #[[1]][q]]]},
     Axes -> True,
     AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
     ImageSize -> {200, 200},
     PlotLabel -> #[[2]]] & /@
  Transpose[{{t[{0, 1}, {0, 0}], r[90 °, {0, 0}], 
     s[{1, 2}]}, {"Reflection", "Rotation", "Translation"}}] //
 Row[#, Spacer[5]] &
```

[image]